# How is this array join producing strings of characters?

Tags: javascript

A problem over at CodeWars is to write a function, `accum(s)`, that does the following:

```
accum("abcd");    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty"); // "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
accum("cwAt");    // "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

An answer to this problem is the following:

```
function accum(s) {
  return s.split('').map((x,index) => x.toUpperCase()+Array(index+1).join(x.toLowerCase())).join('-');
}
```

I am particularly interested in what `x.toUpperCase()+Array(index+1).join(x.toLowerCase())` does.

If I write it in pieces, `Array` outputs `[]`. `Array(1)` outputs `[ ]`. `Array(2)` outputs `[ ,  ]`. That's seems... odd.

Even stranger, `'a' + Array()` outputs `a`, `'a' + Array(1)` seemingly outputs `a` as well, `'a' + Array(2)` outputs `a,`, `'a' + Array(3)` outputs `a,,`. Notice that the angular brackets are gone. I.e., it is not an array. Again, that seems... odd.

Even better, `'a' + Array() + 'b'` outputs `a`, `'a' + Array(1) + 'b'` outputs `a`, `'a' + Array(2) + 'b'` outputs `ab`.

My question is if someone could explain what is happening exactly in all these three cases. In the first case, why does there seem to be a space added going from `Array()` to `Array(1)`? And why does `Array(2)` not output `[,]`, but `[ ,  ]`?

And what happens when a letter is concatenated with `Array(n)`? What is returned by `Array(n)` in this case?

Comment: Outputs where? Where are you trying it and with what code? Have you read the [documentation for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)?

Comment: I guess you could try jFiddle, or just a js file with a console.log. In my case,  I have node.js set up, and just adjust a js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works because it's creating an array with a certain number of elements which are `undefined` by default, then joining them using a letter as a delimiter.

Think of what it would be like if you joined an array of blank strings with a comma delimiter:

```js
// join with blank delimiter
console.log(['A', 'B', 'C'].join(''));

// join with comma delimiter
console.log(['A', 'B', 'C'].join(','));

// join blank strings with comma delimiter
console.log(['', '', ''].join(','));

// join blank strings with letter delimiter
console.log(['', '', ''].join('a'));

// join undefined with letter delimiter
console.log([undefined, undefined, undefined].join('a'));

// join array of undefined with letter delimiter
console.log(Array(3).join('a'));
```

Notice that the last element in the array doesn't get a delimiter, so the result will always have one less character compared to the array length. This is why they use `Array(index+1)` to make the temporary array larger to accommodate an extra delimiter.

Comment: I get what you are saying with the delimiter. That's inventive!

But what about the seemingly strange behavior when taken one piece at a time? E.g., why does `'a' + Array(n)` not return an array? Is it true that `Array()` is an empty array, and `Array(1)` contains the value 'undefined'?  Why does it show up as an empty space, and not 'undefined'?

Comment: You can check all of these things by opening a javascript console and testing. Yes, an array defined with a size needs to put *something* in each item so it becomes an array of `undefined`s. Undefined, like null, will show up as blank when joined or `Array.toString()`. Finally, the "string + array" is converting the array to a string (using the `Array.toString()` method) and then concatenating it to `a`.